# Opening files in net core (C#)

Tags: c#, file, .net-core

I am trying to open a file in net core as I would in full framework.

For example I am trying to open a sql file using: Process.Start(path).

It should have opened it with the default application but instead I get 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path); maybe ?`

Comment: No I am not trying to read the content. I am trying to actually open the file in the OS

Comment: Simple, try `Process.Start("Notepad.exe");` and include `using System.Diagnostics;` should work without fail.

Comment: I dont think you read my post. That is what I did and it did not work and calling exe would work though but  thats not the only thing I want to open

Comment: I guess you're using Linux? Simple plain text files are _not_ executable in Linux.

Comment: Nope I am using Windows 10

Comment: Possibly relevant:  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10361

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the way:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {anyFileName}"));
```

Comment: Also would like to thank @Amy for pointing me to the right direction